# Download binary file over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, download, binaryfiles

I need to download a binary file , uploaded via http post. I can not able to download  file.

I can see the content of data but I'm not able to save into my local disk.

this is what i see in string

--fUYxo2BFe6N Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="EVLD_1.4.36_16_0993_0_000AAE0E0109_2D8A145A040000CC_0E0B1B0F3B29_0008.akt" Content-Type: application/x-gzip

‹ òÖwTcÈ”cdäã–æ7´fàZÇÇÈÉÀÀüA Èåp’Y9,Lp%ì@1& ‹…Äg¬ ‚
,
"8€dÐDÁ
"x@/ˆàü B D‚!!Ä ƒ³e¹!ê™è›è˜™ƒ‘e+R9*ÌG[+‚´möÛÊ€äò0²ª2¬B† --fUYxo2BFe6N Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SehirID"

16 --fUYxo2BFe6N Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CihazTipiID"

64 --fUYxo2BFe6N Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CihazAltTipiID"

1 --fUYxo2BFe6N Content-Disposition: form-data; name="md5"

1FAFE4C67252889C75C526EA4313BE27 --fUYxo2BFe6N Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mac"

000AAE0E0109 --fUYxo2BFe6N--

This is my source code for listenint requests. I can handle de requests but I'm not able to save content into a file..

public class HttpProcessor
    {
        public TcpClient socket;
        public HttpServer srv;

```
    private Stream inputStream;
    public StreamWriter outputStream;

    public String http_method;
    public String http_url;
    public String http_protocol_versionstring;
    public Hashtable httpHeaders = new Hashtable();


    private static int MAX_POST_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB

    public HttpProcessor(TcpClient s, HttpServer srv)
    {
        this.socket = s;
        this.srv = srv;

    }


    private string streamReadLine(Stream inputStream)
    {
        int next_char;
        string data = "";
        while (true)
        {
            next_char = inputStream.ReadByte();
            if (next_char == '\n') { break; }
            if (next_char == '\r') { continue; }
            if (next_char == -1) { Thread.Sleep(1); continue; };
            data += Convert.ToChar(next_char);
        }
        return data;
    }
    public void process()
    {
        // we can't use a StreamReader for input, because it buffers up extra data on us inside it's
        // "processed" view of the world, and we want the data raw after the headers
        inputStream = new BufferedStream(socket.GetStream());

        // we probably shouldn't be using a streamwriter for all output from handlers either
        outputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(socket.GetStream()));
        try
        {
            parseRequest();
            readHeaders();
            if (http_method.Equals("GET"))
            {
                handleGETRequest();
            }
            else if (http_method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                handlePOSTRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
            writeFailure();
        }
        outputStream.Flush();
        // bs.Flush(); // flush any remaining output
        inputStream = null; outputStream = null; // bs = null;            
        socket.Close();
    }

    public void parseRequest()
    {
        String request = streamReadLine(inputStream);
        string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
        if (tokens.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid http request line");
        }

        http_method = tokens[0].ToUpper();
        http_url = tokens[1];
        http_protocol_versionstring = tokens[2];

        Console.WriteLine("starting: " + request);
    }

    public void readHeaders()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("readHeaders()");
        String line;
        while ((line = streamReadLine(inputStream)) != null)
        {
            if (line.Equals(""))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("got headers");
                return;
            }

            int separator = line.IndexOf(':');
            if (separator == -1)
            {
                throw new Exception("invalid http header line: " + line);
            }
            String name = line.Substring(0, separator);
            int pos = separator + 1;
            while ((pos < line.Length) && (line[pos] == ' '))
            {
                pos++; // strip any spaces
            }

            string value = line.Substring(pos, line.Length - pos);
            Console.WriteLine("header: {0}:{1}", name, value);
            httpHeaders[name] = value;
        }
    }

    public void handleGETRequest()
    {
        srv.handleGETRequest(this);
    }

    private const int BUF_SIZE = 4096;
    public void handlePOSTRequest()
    {
        // this post data processing just reads everything into a memory stream.
        // this is fine for smallish things, but for large stuff we should really
        // hand an input stream to the request processor. However, the input stream 
        // we hand him needs to let him see the "end of the stream" at this content 
        // length, because otherwise he won't know when he's seen it all! 

        Console.WriteLine("get post data start");
        int content_len = 0;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (this.httpHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
        {
            content_len = Convert.ToInt32(this.httpHeaders["Content-Length"]);
            if (content_len > MAX_POST_SIZE)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    String.Format("POST Content-Length({0}) too big for this simple server",
                      content_len));
            }
            byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
            int to_read = content_len;
            while (to_read > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("starting Read, to_read={0}", to_read);

                int numread = this.inputStream.Read(buf, 0, Math.Min(BUF_SIZE, to_read));
                Console.WriteLine("read finished, numread={0}", numread);
                if (numread == 0)
                {
                    if (to_read == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("client disconnected during post");
                    }
                }
                to_read -= numread;
                ms.Write(buf, 0, numread);
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //  String s1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());







        }
        Console.WriteLine("get post data end");

        srv.handlePOSTRequest(this, new StreamReader(ms));


    }
    private static Stream GetPostStream(string filePath, string boundary)
    {
        Stream postDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        //adding form data
        string formDataHeaderTemplate = Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundary + Environment.NewLine +
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "{1}";

        //foreach (string key in formData.Keys)
        //{
        //    byte[] formItemBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(formDataHeaderTemplate,
        //    key, formData[key]));
        //    postDataStream.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length);
        //}

        //adding file data
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        string fileHeaderTemplate = Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundary + Environment.NewLine +
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"" +
        Environment.NewLine + "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        byte[] fileHeaderBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(fileHeaderTemplate,
        "UploadCSVFile", fileInfo.FullName));

        postDataStream.Write(fileHeaderBytes, 0, fileHeaderBytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            postDataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] endBoundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--");
        postDataStream.Write(endBoundaryBytes, 0, endBoundaryBytes.Length);

        return postDataStream;
    }


    public void writeSuccess(string content_type = "text/html")
    {
        outputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        outputStream.WriteLine("Content-Type: " + content_type);
        outputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
        outputStream.WriteLine("");
    }

    public void writeFailure()
    {
        outputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 404 File not found");
        outputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
        outputStream.WriteLine("");
    }
}

public abstract class HttpServer
{

    protected int port;
    TcpListener listener;
    bool is_active = true;

    public HttpServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void listen()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(port);
        listener.Start();
        while (is_active)
        {
            TcpClient s = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            HttpProcessor processor = new HttpProcessor(s, this);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processor.process));
            thread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    public abstract void handleGETRequest(HttpProcessor p);
    public abstract void handlePOSTRequest(HttpProcessor p, StreamReader inputData);
}

public class MyHttpServer : HttpServer
{
    public MyHttpServer(int port)
        : base(port)
    {
    }
    public override void handleGETRequest(HttpProcessor p)
    {

        if (p.http_url.Equals("/Test.png"))
        {
            Stream fs = File.Open("../../Test.png", FileMode.Open);

            p.writeSuccess("image/png");
            fs.CopyTo(p.outputStream.BaseStream);
            p.outputStream.BaseStream.Flush();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("request: {0}", p.http_url);
        p.writeSuccess();
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("<html><body><h1>test server</h1>");
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("Current Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("url : {0}", p.http_url);

        p.outputStream.WriteLine("<form method=post action=/form>");
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("<input type=text name=foo value=foovalue>");
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("<input type=submit name=bar value=barvalue>");
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("</form>");
    }

    public override void handlePOSTRequest(HttpProcessor p, StreamReader inputData)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("POST request: {0}", p.http_url);
        string data = inputData.ReadToEnd();



        //SaveStreamToFile(inputData);
        p.writeSuccess();
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("<html><body><h1>test server</h1>");
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("<a href=/test>return</a><p>");
        p.outputStream.WriteLine("postbody: <pre>{0}</pre>", data);


    }




    public void SaveStreamToFile(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream.Length == 0) return;

        // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:/EmreDenemeHttp.txt", (int)stream.Length))
        {
            // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);

            // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
            fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
        }
    }
}



public class TestMain
{
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        HttpServer httpServer;
        if (args.GetLength(0) > 0)
        {
            httpServer = new MyHttpServer(Convert.ToInt16(args[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            httpServer = new MyHttpServer(80);
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(httpServer.listen));
        thread.Start();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: store Content in a string, create a binary file, write to it?

Comment: store Content but how?

Comment: *How* do you *see* it? *Why* can't you save it?

Comment: exactly @AlexK. The Content property must belong to a http response object.

Comment: From your source it seems like you're trying to implement your own HTTP server. This is fine, but "debug this server for me" is too broad of a question. Can you add specific detail and point to a piece of erroneous code? What have you tried? Why don't you use the built-in `HttpListener`?

Comment: I try to read my stream and it's output in above. Actually I dont know the start point. What I should start before. If I use file stream and save it into a file it will not be write correct content. I want to parse content and after parsing, I want to write it to file.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you see this as string in your browser, the mime type sent by your server to your client may be wrong.
By default it is set to text/html.
It should be something like    application/x-binary
or perhaps    application/x-gzip
Check what mime type is fetched by your client when you display the page and act accordingly on your server.

Comment: No, I dont not see this in browser, When I debug the code and write to content into a file. Content of the file is this.